# Как построить на графике sin на максимуме и на минимуме

Tags: python, matplotlib

Как в python можно нарисовать синусоиду заходящую на вершину и на низ графика?

Кусочек кода.

```
x1=[7,-1,-6,1,10]
y1=[2,-2,7,12,22]

plt.plot(x1,y1,color='blue',linewidth=3)

x = np.arange(0,250,0.1)
y = np.sin( (x - 0.01))

plt.plot(x,y,color='red',linewidth=2)
```

И картинка для наглядности.
[image: пример]

Есть идея, как измудриться: нарисовать поверх основного графика ещё один растянутый график, но с осями от -1 до 1.

Но может есть нормальный вариант на одном графике?

PS Речь не о том, чтобы посчитать синусойду правильно, так как меняется масштаб и синусойда опять не у краев. Речь о том, как спомощью стандартных инструментов растянуть синусойду до краев графика.

Comment: Что значит передвинуть сюда? Просто `2*sin(x)`? Или `sin(x)-1`?

Comment: @vp_arth, Чтобы диапазон синусойды менялся не от 1 до -1, а от края низа до края верха графика, всегда, независимо от значений на самом графике.

Comment: Ок, что такое синусойда? Почему она не сйнусойда, к примеру?

Comment: Так вы холст хотите подрезать до границ графика или график растянуть до границ холста?

Comment: @passant, Скорее синусойду растянуть до границ холста. Независимо от того, что на графике. У меня появилась ещё одна идея рисовать синусойду на background на графике. Т.е. сначала рисуем картинку таким же размером, что и график на ней рисуем синусойду и подкладываем под background. Получилось. Но тоже какое-то извращение. Может есть нормальные инструменты для подобного?

Comment: @strawdog -  а что такое "синИсоИда"? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "синусойду растянуть до границ холста" -  это значит, что вам известны максимальное и минимальное значение вашей синусоиды. Ну например, 10. Тогда

> ```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import numpy as np
> х=np.linspace(0, 10, 2000)
> lim=10
> plt.ylim(-lim,lim)
> plt.plot(х,lim*np.sin(х))
> ```

Имеем: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Аналогично, если график надо обрезать до граничных значений синусоиды, то

```
х=np.linspace(0, 10, 2000)
y=15*np.sin(х)
plt.ylim(y.min(),y.max())
plt.plot(х,y)
```

получаем:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Не знал, что лимит можно устанавливать.